# Can't insert into database an autofill fields?

Tags: javascript, php, html

it's my first time asking here,
I've been trying to look for something similar in other questions asked, and couldn't find it.

I have a form with Zip code line(textbox) and State line(textbox),
now, the stateboxes are auto-filled by a javascript by entering a valid US zip code.
the form itself is a bit longer.
I only show the relevant code that has been edited by me,
It was a select menu before (and everything worked just fine - data was entered into databse), and I changed it, so no select will be needed.

There is also css file, but it's irrelevant (designing isn't the issue)

So, here is my html code :

```
<html>
<head>some content here</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<div class="title"><h2>my form title</h2></div><br>
<div align="center" class="element-name">
                             </span>
<span align="center" id="zipbox" class="nameFirst">
<input type="text" class="medium" pattern="[0-9]*" name="col2" id="col2" maxlength="5" placeholder="Type your ZIP code" onkeypress='validate(event)'required/>
                        </span>
<span align="center" id="zipbox2" class="nameLast">
<input type="text" class="medium" pattern="[0-9]*" name="col4" id="col4" maxlength="5" placeholder="Type your ZIP code" onkeypress='validate(event)'required/>
                </span></div>
<div align="center" class="element-name">
<span class="required"></span>
<span align="center" id="statebox" class="nameFirst">
<input type="text" class="medium" name="col1" id="col1" placeholder="" required />
<label class="subtitle">From</label>
                            </span>
<span align="center" id="statebox2" class="nameLast">
<input type="text" class="medium" name="col3" id="col3" placeholder="" required />
<label class="subtitle">To</label>
                               </span></div>
<p align="center"><input type="reset" value="Clear"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

some javescript !

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#col2").keyup(function() {
        var el = $(this);

        if (el.val().length === 5) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                data: "zip=" + el.val(),
                success: function(result, success) {
                    $("#city").val(result.city);
                    $("#col1").val(result.state);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#col4").keyup(function() {
        var el = $(this);

        if (el.val().length === 5) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                data: "zip=" + el.val(),
                success: function(result, success) {
                    $("#city2").val(result.city);
                    $("#col3").val(result.state);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}); 
    </script>
```

and php code to process the form :
- it's 13 columns, but i know for sure that the other values are correct.
- col0 represent the date.

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
 $privatekey = "mycaptchakey";
 $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                 $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
 if (!$resp->is_valid) {
// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
   die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
        "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
        $process = FALSE;
 } else {

   // Your code here to handle a successful verification // Your code here to handle a successful verification
 }
define('CONST_SERVER_TIMEZONE', 'EDT');
define('CONST_SERVER_DATEFORMAT', 'YmdHis');
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


$col0 = $_POST['col0'];
$col1 = strtoupper($_POST['col1']);
$col2 = strtoupper($_POST['col2']);
$col3 = strtoupper($_POST['col3']);
$col4 = strtoupper($_POST['col4']);


if ( isset($col1) && isset($col2) isset($col3) && isset($col4) && $error == FALSE ) {
  $process = TRUE;
} else {
  $process = FALSE;
}
$mode = "mysql";{

define ('DB_USER', 'uname');
define ('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define ('DB_HOST', 'host');
define ('DB_NAME', 'dbname');
$dbc = @mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die('Failure: ' . mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die ('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error() );

$query = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('$current_date','$col1','$col2','$col3','$col4')";
$q = mysql_query($query);

if (!$q) {
  exit("<p>MySQL Insertion failure.</p>");
} else {
  mysql_close();
  //for testing only
  //echo "<p>MySQL Insertion Successful</p>";

}}

  header( 'Location: http://mywebsite.com/index.php' ); 
?>
```

i'm not sure if i'm doing it right but here is my
mytable structure :

```
1 - sid - int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
2 - col0 - date
3 - col1 - text utf8_unicode_ci
4 - col2 - text utf8_unicode_ci
5 - col3 - text utf8_unicode_ci
6 - col4 - text utf8_unicode_ci
and so on up to 12 columons.
```

Help please ! what is going wrong here ?

EDIT :

Thank you very much r3wt for the usefull information, 
there is a lot to fix especially when it comes to the php part of it :)

ok, so i was able to fix the insertion.
i missed a critical value -

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('$current_date','$col1','$col2','$col3','$col4')";
```

should have been:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('','$current_date','$col1','$col2','$col3','$col4')";
```

that's is because all this form info is going into a phpGrid table
and i had a hidden column 'sid' which is automatically beeing filled.

I promise that in the next time I will be prepare with some more knowledge :)

thanks again.

Comment: What is your problem ? What's going on ?

Comment: Could you please post `mytable` structure please?

Comment: This code is asking for SQL injection

Comment: @Dikei not only that there are numerous typographical errors, and his query isn't even a valid SQL statement.

Comment: blue112, auto increment columns don't have to be described in queries. their value is automatically created. i'm telling you, your query is still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This waits until a second has past after they have finished typing in the element, then submits the ajax request.

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#col4").keyup(function() {
        var col4val = $(this).val();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){fillLocation(col4val)}, 1000);
    });

    var timer = null;
    function fillLocation(value){
        $.get('http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com', {zip: value} , function(data){
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#city2").val(result.city);
            $("#col3").val(result.state);
        });
    }
});
```

also, your php code is *considered* to be woefully insecure because you are using mysql.

also, i just noticed a glaring error, you are missing and and operator between $col2 isset and $col3, check your ajax i guarantee you it is returning 500 internal server error:

```
if ( isset($col1) && isset($col2) isset($col3) && isset($col4) && $error == FALSE ) {
  $process = TRUE;
} else {
  $process = FALSE;
}
```

also, your query is wrong. its obvious you are just copy and pasting things together here. go read the mysql manual on `INSERT` statements and go read up on the `mysqli` and `pdo` extensions for php.

A valid mysql statement looks like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (column1,column2,column3) VALUES ('val1','val2','val3')
```

realizing this, you could construct the statement in php like so

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (column1,column2,column3) VALUES ('".$val1."','".$val2."','".$val3."')");
```

if you continue to use mysql you will get your site hacked, its just a matter of time, especially since you don't sanitize any of your data. please make the smart choice and use mysqli or pdo to interface with the database from php.

As per the request of Dikei, i'm going to introduce you briefly to prepared statements with mysqli so that you may learn to use safe methods for interacting with the database.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host','username','password','databasename');
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (column1,column2,column3) VALUES (?,?,?)");//bind your variables in the same order!

//s for a string, d for a double floating point integer, and i for unsigned int.
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$col1,$col2,$col3);
if($stmt->execute()) {
    $row = $stmt->insert_id ?: null;
    if(!empty($row))
    {
        //query success
    }else{
        //query failure
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

if you need more info, i provided a broader example of working with mysqli using the Object Oriented approach here(its in part two of the answer): [login session destroyed after refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396744/login-session-destroyed-after-refresh/24397454#24397454)

Comment: Your example using string concatenation are is not injection-safe. You should provide an example using parameterized query, the safeset way to insert data.

Comment: @Dikei do you realy think he's going to understand it if i do?

Comment: this is true i'm mostly copy paste things, my thing is coolate everything in order.
can u help me with the java script? i didn't understood what exactly to replace and where?

Comment: He'll have to understand sooner or later ;). Even if he don't understand it now (no offense quadra), at least the code he copy/paste will be correct :).

Comment: none taken, it's a rough demo eitherway :)
i appreciate your help very much!

Comment: I just updated the jquery code. oh btw, you're not even returning a success object to your javascript. you really need to start out with something easier, i don't have time to hold your hand and walk you through it.

Comment: i know it sounds unlikely, but the states are not showing up, although it seems to b proper (i copied and change col4 to col2 for the other script)

Comment: If i understand correctly, you are doing a cross site ajax request? yeah, that's not supported by default.

Comment: solved my problem -> edited in my post !
thank you for the usefull information r3wt.